# Calendar invitation is not being sent properly to Microsoft Outlook account

Tags: python, boto3, icalendar, mime, amazon-ses

I am testing my code for sending event invitations via email and am seeing an unexpected response when I add headers to the MIMEText object in my code.

My code with headers is as follows (omitting some code for brevity):

```
class PersonInfo:
    def __init__(self, name, email):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email

def build_cal_event(evName, evDesc, \
              organizer, attendees,\
              startDate, endDate):

str_list = []
str_list.append('''\...... #NOT SHOWING FUNCTION IMPLEMENTATION FOR CONCISENESS

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sender = PersonInfo("MYNAME", "ID@gmail.com")
    rec1= PersonInfo("RECNAME", "ID@outlook.com")
    recipients = [rec1]
    subject = "Hi"
    body = "How is everything?"

    dtstart = datetime(2020, 9, 2, 21, 30, 0)
    dtend = datetime(2020, 9, 3, 22, 30, 0)
  
    ics = build_cal_event("ImpEvent", "Greeting", sender, recipients, dtstart, dtend) #Function creates ICS file

    with open("event.ics", 'w') as f:
        f.write(ics)

    client = boto3.client('ses',region_name="us-east-1")
    
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    
    msg["Subject"] = subject
    msg["From"] = sender.email
    msg["To"] = ', '.join(map(lambda x: x.email, recipients))
    msg["Content-class"] = "urn:content-classes:calendarmessage"

    part_cal = MIMEText(ics,'calendar;method=REQUEST')

    part = MIMEText(body)
    msg.attach(part)

    icsName = "{}.ics".format(subject.replace(" ", "_").upper())
    part_cal.set_payload(ics)
    encoders.encode_base64(part_cal)
    part_cal.add_header('Content-Type', 'text/calendar')
    part_cal.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename={}".format(icsName))

    msg.attach(part_cal)
 
    try:
        result = client.send_raw_email(
            Source=msg['From'],
            Destinations=[recipient.email for recipient in recipients],
            RawMessage={'Data': msg.as_string()}
        )
        print(result['MessageId']) 
    except ClientError as e:
        print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
```

When I run the above code, I see the following response on Outlook:

[image]

As you can see, I do not see the Accept, Tentative and Decline buttons in the email invitation.

My ICS file is as follows:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:REQUEST
PRODID:OrganizationName
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Eastern Standard Time
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:16010101T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:-0400
TZOFFSETTO:-0500
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=11
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:16010101T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
TZOFFSETTO:-0400
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=2SU;BYMONTH=3
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
ORGANIZER;CN=MYNAME:mailto:ID@gmail.com
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN=MYNAME:
 mailto:ID@outlook.com
DESCRIPTION;LANGUAGE=en-US:impevent
UID:7c8feffa-f03d-406b-8195-3587ec426ec6
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-US:ImpEvent
DTSTART;TZID=Eastern Standard Time:20200902T213000
DTEND;TZID=Eastern Standard Time:20200903T223000
CLASS:PUBLIC
PRIORITY:5
DTSTAMP:20200902T025908Z
TRANSP:OPAQUE
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SEQUENCE:0
LOCATION;LANGUAGE=en-US:
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-APPT-SEQUENCE:0
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-OWNERAPPTID:2118692743
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:TENTATIVE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INTENDEDSTATUS:BUSY
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-ALLDAYEVENT:FALSE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INSTTYPE:0
X-MICROSOFT-ONLINEMEETINGEXTERNALLINK:
X-MICROSOFT-ONLINEMEETINGCONFLINK:
X-MICROSOFT-DONOTFORWARDMEETING:FALSE
X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE
X-MICROSOFT-LOCATIONS:[]
BEGIN:VALARM
DESCRIPTION:REMINDER
TRIGGER;RELATED=START:-PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

However, when I comment out the `add_header` lines from the above code in this way:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sender = PersonInfo("MYNAME", "ID@gmail.com")
    rec1= PersonInfo("RECNAME", "ID@outlook.com")
    recipients = [rec1]
    subject = "Hi"
    body = "How is everything?"
    
    dtstart = datetime(2020, 9, 2, 21, 30, 0)
    dtend = datetime(2020, 9, 3, 22, 30, 0)
  
    ics = build_cal_event("ImpEvent", "Greeting", sender, recipients, dtstart, dtend) #Function creates ICS file

    with open("event.ics", 'w') as f:
        f.write(ics)

    client = boto3.client('ses',region_name="us-east-1")

    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')

    msg["Subject"] = subject
    msg["From"] = sender.email
    msg["To"] = ', '.join(map(lambda x: x.email, recipients))
    msg["Content-class"] = "urn:content-classes:calendarmessage"

    part_cal = MIMEText(ics,'calendar;method=REQUEST')

    part = MIMEText(body)
    msg.attach(part)

    icsName = "{}.ics".format(subject.replace(" ", "_").upper())
    part_cal.set_payload(ics)
    encoders.encode_base64(part_cal)
    #part_cal.add_header('Content-Type', 'text/calendar')
    #part_cal.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename={}".format(icsName))

    msg.attach(part_cal)

    try:
        result = client.send_raw_email(
            Source=msg['From'],
            Destinations=[recipient.email for recipient in recipients],
            RawMessage={'Data': msg.as_string()}
        )
        print(result['MessageId']) 
    except ClientError as e:
        print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
```

I see the expected and correct response:

[image]

I do not understand why the recipient cannot see the event invitation properly when I include the `add_header` lines in my code. Could it be due to the `send_raw_email` command in my code?

**EDIT 1:**

I have noticed that the event name and details are absent in the second snippet. What could be a reason for this?

**EDIT 2:**

After Hernán Alarcón's suggestion, I changed my relevant code in the following way:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sender = PersonInfo("MYNAME", "ID@gmail.com")
    rec1= PersonInfo("RECNAME", "ID@outlook.com")
    recipients = [rec1]
    subject = "Hi"
    body = "How is everything?"
    
    dtstart = datetime(2020, 9, 2, 21, 30, 0)
    dtend = datetime(2020, 9, 3, 22, 30, 0)
  
    ics = build_cal_event("ImpEvent", "Greeting", sender, recipients, dtstart, dtend) #Function creates ICS file

    with open("event.ics", 'w') as f:
        f.write(ics)

    client = boto3.client('ses',region_name="us-east-1")

    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')

    msg["Subject"] = subject
    msg["From"] = sender.email
    msg["To"] = ', '.join(map(lambda x: x.email, recipients))
    msg["Content-class"] = "urn:content-classes:calendarmessage"

    part_cal = MIMEText(ics,'calendar;method=REQUEST')

    part = MIMEText(body)
    msg.attach(part)

    icsName = "{}.ics".format(subject.replace(" ", "_").upper())
    part_cal.set_payload(ics)
    #encoders.encode_base64(part_cal)
    part_cal.add_header('Content-Type', 'text/calendar')
    part_cal.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename={}".format(icsName))

    msg.attach(part_cal)

    try:
        result = client.send_raw_email(
            Source=msg['From'],
            Destinations=[recipient.email for recipient in recipients],
            RawMessage={'Data': msg.as_string()}
        )
        print(result['MessageId']) 
    except ClientError as e:
        print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
```

It produced the following response:

[image]

The Accept, Tentative and Decline buttons are not present in the received email even after the code change.

**EDIT 3:**

```
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="===============3470341632134321988=="
MIME-Version: 1.0
Subject: Hi
From: ID@gmail.com
To: ID@outlook.com
Content-class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage

--===============3470341632134321988==
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

How is everything?
--===============3470341632134321988==
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/calendar; method="REQUEST"; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
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--===============3470341632134321988==--
```

Comment: Do you have to have to encode the calendar part in base64? [This example](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/email-examples.html#id2) only does it for MIMEBase not for MIMEText. I'm guessing that the encoding is not compatible with the content type. The same example never sets the content type, but sets the content-disposition. I would suggest not to encode, set the content-disposition and see what happens.

Comment: @HernánAlarcón Thank you for the response. Do you mean I should remove the lines     `encoders.encode_base64(part_cal)` from my code?

Comment: @HernánAlarcón Even after commenting out the encoding command, the invitation is not being sent properly. I am only seeing the attached ics file in the received email. Please view by edit for more details.

Comment: And if you do not set the content-type?

Comment: @HernánAlarcón I get the same response. I just get a plain email with the ics file attached to it.

Comment: @HernánAlarcón I have added the mime email to my question